# Guarantee max output length of double with setprecision for default output format

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a `double` that I want to store in a string as losslessly as possible, but the storage format has a maximum string length of 16 that makes this impossible (because `std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10` indicates we need 17 precision for this).  So, accounting for the possibility of the characters `-` and `.`, we might clamp it to 14 or 15 as follows:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
std::string format(T val)
{
  int precision = std::min(std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10, 
    val >= 0.0 ? 15 : 14);
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss.precision(precision);
  oss << val;
  return oss.str();
}
```

However, with the default formatting the output could be in scientific notation and the result might still overrun the bounds.  For example, this input:

`7.105427357601002e-14`

Needs precision lowered to 12 before it gives a short enough output:

`7.1054273576e-14`

So, how can I compute the maximum precision that will keep the output within my length constraint without a brute force approach like retrying with lower precision if the result is too long?

Comment: Are you trying to left (right) trim the long-double literal, round it or get the numeric limits based on the template type?

Comment: @Ron The question is basically: "Given the size of my storage (in bytes), how do I print a `double` to the maximum precision possible that fits in that length"

Comment: Meta question: How much precision do you actually need for your application? How much (relative/absolute) error is  acceptable? Are you sure computation error does not dominate that anyways?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that converting the `double` to base10 creates new rounding error anyways, so *"full precision in decimal"* is somewhat dodgy to begin with.

Comment: Do you have to pre-compute it? You could measure the actual length and retry with a lower limit if it didn't fit.

Comment: @BaummitAugen True, but if we have `std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10` precision in text form then we can round-trip the exact `double` value.  Digits beyond this don't matter for text storage because they all collapse to the same `double` value.

Comment: @harold It can be run-time computed as in the negative/non-negative test in my original example, but I'm hoping for something that doesn't involve fully formatting it and then retrying if the result is too long.

Comment: From the standard it looks like that the default ostream for floating point is `%g` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put ), and it looks like `%g` formatting switches to scientific when the value has an exponent < -4 ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf ).

Answer (score 0):

As @bsruth noted, the default format is equivalent to `%g` for `fprintf`, and that is specified with this behavior:

> Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is not specified, or 1 if the precision is ​0​.
>   Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:
>
> > if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f or F and precision P − 1 − X.
> >       otherwise, the conversion is with style e or E and precision P − 1.

So, we calculate the base10 exponent as it would be in scientific notation and use that to adjust precision down if needed:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

double frexp10_scientific(double arg, int* exp)
{
   *exp = (arg == 0) ? 0 : static_cast<int>(std::log10(std::fabs(arg)));
   double fraction = arg * pow(10 , -(*exp));
   // adjust to scientific format decomposition
   if (std::fabs(fraction) < 1.0) {
       *exp -= 1;
       fraction *= 10;
   }
   return fraction;
}

template <typename T>
int precision_needed(T val)
{
  // initial guess on precision
  int precision;
  if (val >= 0.0) {
    if (val >= 1e15 && val < 1e16)
      precision = 16; // all integer digits used
    else
      precision = 15; // '.' present
  } else {
    if (val > -1e15 && val <= -1e14)
      precision = 15; // '-' present, all integer digits used
    else
      precision = 14; // '-' and '.' present
  }

  int exp;
  frexp10_scientific(val, &exp);

  // adjust for scientific notation if needed
  if (exp < -99) {
    precision -= 5; // "e-123"
  } else if (exp < -4) {
    precision -= 4; // "e-01"
  } else if (exp >= precision) {
    if (exp > 99) {
      precision -= 5; // "e+123"
    } else {
      precision -= 4; // "e+12"
    }
  }

  return std::min(precision, std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10);
}

template <typename T>
std::string format(T val) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss.precision(precision_needed(val));
  oss << val;
  return oss.str();
}
```

Some [test cases](http://cpp.sh/8fces), showing input, precision, length and output:

```
1.123e-4: [p=15,l=9] 0.0001123
1.123e-5: [p=11,l=9] 1.123e-05
1.123e-99: [p=11,l=9] 1.123e-99
1.123e-100: [p=10,l=10] 1.123e-100
7.105427357601002e-14: [p=11,l=16] 7.1054273576e-14
7.105427357621342e-14: [p=11,l=16] 7.1054273576e-14
-7.105427357601002e-14: [p=10,l=16] -7.105427358e-14
-7.105427357621342e-14: [p=10,l=16] -7.105427358e-14
7.105427357621342e14: [p=15,l=15] 710542735762134
7.105427357621342e15: [p=16,l=16] 7105427357621342
7.105427357621342e16: [p=11,l=16] 7.1054273576e+16
-7.105427357621342e14: [p=15,l=16] -710542735762134
-7.105427357621342e15: [p=10,l=16] -7.105427358e+15
7.105427357621342e15: [p=16,l=16] 7105427357621342
7.105427357621342e16: [p=11,l=16] 7.1054273576e+16
-7.105427357621342e15: [p=10,l=16] -7.105427358e+15
1.123e14: [p=15,l=15] 112300000000000
1.123e15: [p=16,l=16] 1123000000000000
1e15: [p=16,l=16] 1000000000000000
1e16: [p=11,l=5] 1e+16
-1e15: [p=10,l=6] -1e+15
-1e14: [p=15,l=16] -100000000000000
1.2345678901234567890e-14: [p=11,l=16] 1.2345678901e-14
```